# How to set text formatting in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

**Question:** 
can i set text in iOS like bellow image? any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

You will have to create a `UITextView` as usual and add the image as a subview in a `UIImageView`.

```
yourTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
yourTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
yourTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20];

yourTextView.text = @"The year was 1572. Pratap Singh had just become the Maharana of Mewar and he had not been back in Chittor since 1567. His old fort and his home beckoned to him. The pain of his father's death, and the fact that his father had not been able to see Chittor again, troubled the young Maharana deeply. But he was not the only one troubled at this time. Akbar had control of Chittor but not the kingdom of Mewar. So long as the people of Mewar swore by their Maharana, Akbar could not realize his ambition of being the Jahanpanah of Hindustan.";
[self.view addSubview:yourTextView];

yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
yourImageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, self.view.frame.size.width-100, (self.view.frame.size.width-100)*1.5 );

yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageOfAnOldSamurai.png"];
[yourTextView addSubview:yourImageView];
```

To make the text inside the textview wrap around the image, use `exclusionPaths` which is a `UIBezierPath` with the frame from the imageview.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    UIBezierPath * exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:yourImageView.frame];
    yourTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths  = @[exclusionPath];
}
```

The code above creates this result for me:
[image]

Comment: i tried with your code, of course it helped me . but in my case , some characters trimmed.

Comment: yeah of course the code is just a sample - glad I could help!